# Dog was starving himself

Tags: dogs, behavior, eating

One of our three Italian Greyhounds liked to play with his food. About 4 weeks ago we sometimes used to throw some food around for him until we realized he would wait for us to throw him his food and not eat otherwise. So we stopped throwing him his food, only putting his bowl out on certain times a day, to eat. After a while he stopped whining to make us throw his food and we thought the problem was solved, leaving the bowl out throughout the day as we had done for the previous 8 years with no problems.

Yesterday we were looking at him, and realized his ribs were sticking out. Unusualy so. We weighed him and it turns out he has lost more than on kilogram. That's more than fifteen percent of his usual weight.

We've tried hand feeding him now and he will eat the entire bowl out of hand. We're going to try and keep this up for a few days to see if the problem is really only his appetite, and not some sort of worm.

So the problem: he will not eat out of the bowl, from the ground, from a plate... will only eat moving food (like from your hand, or if you throw it..). It doesn't seem to be a "wannabe alpha" kind of problem, since he was just starving himself to the point were he must have constantly been terribly hungry.

Please... any thoughts?

Comment: A quick question: where is the bowl? Are all areas where you have left the bowls accessible to all dogs? A wild guess would be: the others keep him from eating unless YOU are the one offering the food by hand.